# Generate an email when a list item expires

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list

I'm currently using SharePoint 365. Is there a way to generate an email for a monthly expiration of different line items on a pre-existing list? I have access to SharePoint designer if that helps. I have no idea where to begin, links to resources would help greatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a Flow running on a schedule, once per day. Have the Flow query the list for items that have expired, and process them accordingly. https://flow.microsoft.com

You might be able to use SPD for this but Flow is going to be a lot easier to use and is the future of process automation in the Microsoft ecosystem.

Comment: This looks really simple, I think I'll look into getting this. Thank you!

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I documented my process of doing this [in this Q&A](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/296610/how-to-send-email-notification-for-list-items-that-have-expired-or-will-expire-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Loop and “pause for duration” action to send email monthly until deadline.

Check the similar post and answer: [SharePoint 2013 Workflow Email Reminder 3 month, 1 month, due date email reminders](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64ec7e9d-a16a-446d-9b6a-31b9067b626a/sharepoint-2013-workflow-email-reminder-3-month-1-month-due-date-email-reminders?forum=sharepointcustomization)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll look more into detail on this.