# How to send email notification for list items that have expired or will expire in the next 30 days using OData Filter Query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-list, odata

*This started as a question, but I figured out the answer as I went, so just posting for reference.*

**Desired Behaviour**

Use the `OData Filter Query` field in the SharePoint [Get Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items) action in Power Automate to get list items that have already expired or are about to expire and send an email notification containing details about them.

**What I've Tried**

I have three date-only columns:

```
Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date  
End_x0020_of_x0020_Life  
Contract_x0020_End_x0020_Date
```

The columns do not require values, therefore they may or may not have a value.

I want to create a flow that sends a notification when the following conditions are true:

- if any of the date values of these columns are in the past
- if any of the date values of these columns are within the next 30 days

I have successfully defined this logic [in column formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68360532) with:

```
  "style": {
    "color": "=if(Number([$Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date]) == 0, '', if([$Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date]>(@now +2592000000), 'green', if([$Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date]>@now && [$DueDate]< (@now +2592000000), 'Red', 'Red'))"
  }
```

The logic is saying:

- if there is no date, then don't apply color
- if there is a date, more than 30 days in the future, make text green
- if there is a date, within 30 days, make text red
- for everything else (ie for dates in the past), make text red

I am now trying to recreate this logic using `OData Filter Query` in the SharePoint [Get Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-items) action.

**Related Reading**

[OData query operators supported in the SharePoint REST service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service)

[OData Filter query in SharePoint Get items in Power Automate](https://sharepains.com/2018/11/12/sharepoint-get-items-odata-filter-query/)

Answer (score 0):

So the requirements are:

**1)** Start with a `Scheduled Cloud Flow` and `Get Items` action with the `Filter Query` defined below

**2)**  Define the syntax to use when applying multiple filters in an OData filter:

[It looks like](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/OData-filter-combining-multiple-or-statements-with-and/m-p/168067/highlight/true#M17044) this is as simple as using a combination of `and` and `or` operators, and brackets `()` if required:

```
condition_01 and (condition_02 or condition_03)
```

**3)**  Define actual logic to use:

This successfully returns all items, that have a date, where the date is before today ([based on this](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/FLOW-Get-Items-Filter-SharePoint-list-on-Date/m-p/86029/highlight/true#M8491)):

```
Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date lt '@{utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

To use the `date is in the past` logic for all three fields, it seems I can use:

```
Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date lt '@{utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')}' or End_x0020_of_x0020_Life lt '@{utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')}' or Contract_x0020_End_x0020_Date lt '@{utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')}'
```

*I can also initialize a variable above the `Get Items` action, where the value is the expression `utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')`, and reference that variable, rather running a new expression for each condition.*

The `date is within the next 30 days` logic seems to be:

```
Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date gt '@{variables('utc_now')}' and Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date lt '@{variables('utc_now_plus_30_days')}'
```

where I have previously initialized the variables:

```
utc_now = utcNow('yyyy-MM-dd')
utc_now_plus_30_days = addDays(utcNow(),30,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

So putting all 3 columns together, with both logic checks (`in the past` and `in the next 30 days`) looks like:

```
Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date lt '@{variables('utc_now')}' or End_x0020_of_x0020_Life lt '@{variables('utc_now')}' or Contract_x0020_End_x0020_Date lt '@{variables('utc_now')}' or (Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date gt '@{variables('utc_now')}' and Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date lt '@{variables('utc_now_plus_30_days')}') or (End_x0020_of_x0020_Life gt '@{variables('utc_now')}' and End_x0020_of_x0020_Life lt '@{variables('utc_now_plus_30_days')}') or (Contract_x0020_End_x0020_Date gt '@{variables('utc_now')}' and Contract_x0020_End_x0020_Date lt '@{variables('utc_now_plus_30_days')}')
```

**4)**  Setup email content and send the email

After the `Get Items`:

- Add a [Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/data-operations#use-the-select-action) action
- If you want to later display the count of items returned in your email, initialize a string variable (eg `item_count`) with the expression value: `length(body('Select'))`
- Initialize a blank string variable (eg `item_rows`) that you can append details about each item
- Add an `Apply to each`, where the input is `@{body('Select')}`
- Within the loop, append to the string variable `item_rows` referencing details from the `Select`, eg `@{items('Apply_to_each')?['SomePropertyHere']}`, add a `</br>` at the end of each line
- Add a [Send an email (V2)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#send-an-email-(v2)) action and the `item_rows` in the body (make sure to be in `</>` view, so that it handles your `</br>` values correctly.

`Aside:`

Interestingly, if I use `Get Items`, without any filter, and then copy and paste the results into a code editor, and then search for `Lease_x0020_Expiry_x0020_Date` there are only 11 instances of it, even though there are 30 items in the list.  It seems, therefore, that `Get Items` only returns properties, if a value has been defined for the associated field.